# Combining a 1-column data frame with values from a list

Tags: r, append

So I have one column called 'Number' and it has this output

```
Number
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
180
190
200
```

and another output called 'Value' which has this output

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.2231071

[[2]]
[1] 0.3432919

[[3]]
[1] 0.0002351737

[[4]]
[1] 0.01550648

[[5]]
[1] 0.000560943

[[6]]
[1] 2.168151e-06
```

This goes up to 20 values
So I want append this two ouputs together....So I would want a data frame looking like this

```
Number Values
10     0.2231071
20     0.3432919
30     0.0002351737
```

etc...up to 200...how do I do that?
something like `data.frame(Number,Values...??)`

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your two objects are `Numbers` and `Values` then you can just do

```
data.frame(Number, unlist(Value))
```

Comment: @FlayAuchter If you find any answer satisfactory, don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `cbind` or `data.frame`:

```
cbind(Number, Values=unlist(Value))
```